# Странное поведение селекта

Tags: python, django

Почему в селектах в первом случае отображается `SECURITY_WITH`, а во втором - `display2`? Ведь все идентично, по сути ...

Вообще в обеих случаях должна отображаться переведенная фраза с `django.po`. Но как этого добиться, не пойму?

Скриптов, которые могли бы влиять на разметку, вроде нет.

**models.py**

```
CONFIRMATION_WITHOUT = 'display1'
CONFIRMATION_WITH = 'display2'                 #`display2` отображается

CONFIRMATION_CHOICES = (
    (CONFIRMATION_WITHOUT, _('Display1')),
    (CONFIRMATION_WITH, _('Display2')),
)

SECURITY_WITHOUT = 'Display1'
SECURITY_WITH = 'Display2'                      #`SECURITY_WITH` отображается

SECURITY_CHOICES = (
    ('SECURITY_WITHOUT', _('Display1')),
    ('SECURITY_WITH', _('Display2')),
)

income_proof = models.CharField(_('proof'), max_length=255, choices=CONFIRMATION_CHOICES, default=CONFIRMATION_WITHOUT)
security = models.CharField(_('security'), max_length=255, choices=SECURITY_CHOICES, default=SECURITY_WITHOUT)
```

**forms.py**

```
security = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CreditPayment.objects.values_list('security', flat=True).distinct(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': "selectpicker form-control", 'title':_("Security")}))
income_proof = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CreditPayment.objects.values_list('income_proof', flat=True).distinct(), widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'selectpicker form-control', 'title':_("Income proof")}))
```

**template**

```
{{ big_form.security }}
{{ big_form.income_proof }}
```

Comment: Во-первых, ни в одном из случаев переведенная фраза отображаться НЕ должна, потому что вы забираете сырой ключ селекта из базы без какого-либо перевода. Во-вторых, `SECURITY_WITH` отображается, потому что вы его так и прописали `'SECURITY_WITH'` внутри `SECURITY_CHOICES`

Comment: ой, только сейчас заметил))

Comment: чтобы перевод был, нужно переводить именно значения переменных? или же есть способ вытаскивать второй (первый) элемент из кортежа?

Comment: Вообще, я что-то не могу понять, что этот код делает. Для чего вам тут ModelChoiceField? Он предназначен для выбора объекта модели, а вы его заставляете выбирать почему-то строку, и это ломает мне мозг

Comment: Как правильно, подскажите. Я передаю queryset из соответствующих полей модели `CreditPayment`

Comment: К примеру, есть 2 записи: в первой выбрано значение 1, во второй - 3. Вообще предлагается в селекте (в админке 3 вариант: 1, 2, 3). Но так как выбраны только значения 1 и 3, то на фронт пользователю в форму отдаём селект всего из двух значений - 1 и 3.

Comment: А для ModelChoiceField нужны модели, а не поля моделей. И я в итоге ничего не понимаю

Comment: хм... тогда нужен обычный ChoiceField. Просто сформировать для него соответствующий кортеж значений?

Comment: Возможно. И ChoiceField сам всё переведёт, если вы в него запихнёте SECURITY_CHOICES

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.